# SSRS - Naming Excel Tabs based on Page Number/Contents

Tags: reporting-services

My SSRS Report has two 'pages'. 
The first page [run time] shows a Text Box with the Criteria used for returning data.
The next page[s] has all the data.

I have given the Tablix Member for the Data pages the Page Name of 'Detail'.

When the report is exported to Excel, it is displayed on two Sheets. 
The first Sheet [with the Criteria] is named "Sheet1".
The second Sheet [with all the Detail Data] is named "Detail" - which is how I want it.

How do I get the First Sheet [... currently being named "Sheet1"] to be named 'Criteria' when it is exported to  Excel?

Can I use an Expression somewhere that says something like this:

```
IIf (PageNumber = 1, "Criteria", "Detail")
```

?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a conditional expression for this. You can use the `PageName` property to control the sheet names. You can give each table a separate page name. If there are no tables on the first page, insert a rectangle and give that a page name. In the Report properties there is also an `InitialPageName` you can use for the first page. Lastly, make sure that you do have a `PageBreak` defined, don't just let it roll over to the next page based on the height.

Comment: Thanks, @StevenWhite. That worked just like I needed! Appreciate your help!

Comment: P.S. The Tablix that appears on the second page has a 'Page Break Before...' . Thanks.